# Algorithm: Fit smaller strings together optimally to make longer strings of specified length?

Tags: string, algorithm, optimization

**General problem**

I have a set of short strings, each of different length with minimum X > 0 and maximum Y. What is an algorithm which will optimally fit together these short strings to make long strings of length M, where M >> Y? Optimal would be defined as the greatest number of long strings with lengths closest to M as possible.

**Details**

I am writing a tweet creator to practice javascript. I have a list of greetings and a list of account names. I want my program to create tweets such that each tweet has one greeting and the rest of the characters are used for account names. Each tweet has a limit of 140 characters.

```
Hello! @person1 @acc2 @mygoodfriend3 ...
```

Of course, each account has a different number of characters. I want each tweet to use up as many of the 140 characters as possible by optimally selecting combinations of account names.

I am pretty certain there is a class of problems / algorithm that is known to solve this problem but I can't remember it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of problem is called a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), and an exact (or exactly optimal) solution is famous for being intractable.

However, there are reasonable approximate solvers, as well as a "pseudo-polynomial time" dynamic-programming algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to the knapsack problem; it  is a particular case of "multiple linear bin packing problem". Both are NP-hard problems. [Here](http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/classes/funAlgo/05f/lect/l5.pdf) you can find a greedy algorithm for the linear bin packing problem, but the multiple case is much harder. A constraint programming language/library would help to solve these kind of problems.